# does 1 client message trigger all message handlers in websocket++ 0.3X?

Tags: c++, websocket, handler, message, websocket++

I just learned websockets but am still c++ ignorant.

I'm using websocket++ 0.3X, and it is a veritable godsend (can't wait for 1.0).  If there are multiple concurrent connections, and one client sends the server a message, will the message trigger the handlers of all other clients?  If not, how can this be done?  (Is this multithreading?)

What I want to do is the obvious: update the database via a message from a client then update any other clients currently viewing the fields updated.

Sources:

http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/

https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The on_message handler will be called only in the connection that received the message. That connection is responsible for updating the database and signaling to your program to send an update out to all other clients.

Take a look at the broadcast server example here: http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/server-initiated-messages for a simple example of how to set this up.